# MySQL how to use a column with "-" in its name?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using MySQL for Windows 7. I have a column which has a "-" (minus) in its name. Somehow I can not run the following command:

```
INSERT INTO table (..., var-name, ...) VALUES(..., value, ...);
```

Can somebody please help me how I can execute this command?

Using

```
INSERT INTO table (..., [var-name], ...) VALUES(..., value, ...);
```

did not work

Comment: Enclose in backticks.  That is the typical escape character for MySQL:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html.

Comment: ...or you could use underscores instead of dashes, which I don't believe would require any escaping.

Comment: A far, far better idea is to avoid such column names. The present situation is positively distastrous, as an incorrect query wouldn't necessarily error out

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the name with backticks (**`**) like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (..., `var-name`, ...) VALUES(..., value, ...);
```

In order to escape the dash caracter.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL escape character for column names is not `[`, it's `` ` ``

So you need to use:

```
INSERT INTO table (..., `var-name`, ...) VALUES(..., value, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

An accident waiting to happen...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table (plusses INT NOT NULL, minuses INT NOT NULL, `plusses-minuses` INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(10,2,6),
(12,6,6),
(13,9,6),
(14,12,6),
(15,2,6);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+---------+---------+-----------------+
| plusses | minuses | plusses-minuses |
+---------+---------+-----------------+
|      10 |       2 |               6 |
|      12 |       6 |               6 |
|      13 |       9 |               6 |
|      14 |      12 |               6 |
|      15 |       2 |               6 |
+---------+---------+-----------------+

SELECT plusses, minuses, plusses-minuses FROM my_table;
+---------+---------+-----------------+
| plusses | minuses | plusses-minuses |
+---------+---------+-----------------+
|      10 |       2 |               8 |
|      12 |       6 |               6 |
|      13 |       9 |               4 |
|      14 |      12 |               2 |
|      15 |       2 |              13 |
+---------+---------+-----------------+
```